# What kind of connector is this and where do I find it?

Tags: electrical, wiring, valve, engineering, connectors

I recently bought some electric solenoid valves online, and I don't know what kind of electrical connector this is using, and where to get a female version.

[image: The valve in question]

Does anyone know where I can find the female version of this so I can attach it to a pair of long wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some parts of the planet, those are called "[spade connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_connector#Ring_and_spade_terminal)" and are available in crimp-on form.

The sizes are colour coded

They are sold in most auto-parts stores as well as by electrical retailers like Digikey.

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out I just bought the wrong size of female spade terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Those look to me like male "flag" terminals, so maybe one just uses single wires with female flag terminals.  For example:

http://www.allelectronics.com/item/6225/1/4-fully-insulated-female-blue/1.html

Comment: Yup, that's them, common as can be.  Look in automotive.

Comment: "*Spade*" terminal/connector is a more common term to describe these types of connectors.  "*Flag*" terminals are a type of spade terminal, which have the wire connection perpendicular to the connector.